# Windows Boot Process

Tags: windows, boot

In Windows:
System Partition: Contain hardware specific files for boot(NTLDR, Boot.ini and ntdetect.com etc)
Boot Partition: Operating System files

A partition can be both system and boot but this is not required and there can be two separate partitions one for system and the second for boot.

When a partition is both system and boot, there will be no problem and everything(boot files + OS files) will be in that partition plus Boot sector. Am i Right?

Confusion arrives when there are separate partitions for system and boot.

- Where will be Boot sector when
  separate partitions? In System
  partition?
- Will Boot sector always present in System partition?
- Is there any other Boot sector that is associated with each Boot partition?
- Normally in Windows XP the first partition is both System and Boot. In VISTA/W7 normally there is a separate System partition, this partition only contains the boot files(Boot Configuration Data, bootmgr etc) for booting. Is this configuration mandatory for VISTA/W7? Can we also do this for Windows XP?

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this Microsoft Support article : [Definitions for system volume and boot volume](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314470).

> **System volume**
>
> The system volume refers to the disk
>   volume that contains the
>   hardware-specific files that are
>   needed to start Windows, such as
>   Ntldr, Boot.ini, and Ntdetect.com.
>
> On computers that are running the
>   Intel x86 line of CPU processors and
>   later versions, the system volume must
>   be a primary volume that is marked as
>   active. This requirement can be
>   fulfilled on any drive on the computer
>   that the system BIOS searches when the
>   operating system starts.
>
> The system volume can be the same
>   volume as the boot volume. However,
>   this configuration is not required.
>
> **Boot volume**
>
> The boot volume refers to the disk
>   volume that contains the Windows
>   operating system files and the
>   supporting files. By default, the
>   Windows operating system files are in
>   the WINDOWS folder, and the supporting
>   files are in the WINDOWS\System32
>   folder.
>
> The boot volume can be the same volume
>   as the system volume. However, this
>   configuration is not required.
>
> There is only one system volume.
>   However, there is one boot volume for
>   each operating system in a multiboot
>   system.